# "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE MRE_UHAUL as (

  select OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date as start_date
        ,TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((
           LEAD(Rental_date) over
             (partition by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size
                  order by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date
              )),
           'YYYYMMDD')-1, 'YYYYMMDD') as end_date
        ,Rate

    from ( select OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date, Avg(RATE) as RATE
             from mre_competitor_data
             where competitor='UHAUL'
             group by OUTBOUND, INBOUND, vehicle_size, rental_date)

    where rental_date <= (select cpd from mre_system_parameters)

);
```

when I try to run it, it says :

> SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: I don't know. But why are you invoking `TO_DATE` on `LEAD(Rental_date)`? Isn't `rental_date` a date already? You treat it as if it were a string formatted YYYYMMDD. And why do you convert the resulting date with `TO_CHAR`? Isn't the `end_date` supposed to be a date? You should store dates as dates of course, not as strings. Always use the appropriate data type.

Comment: Are you doing a `to_date` on a date field (i.e. calling `to_date` on `lead(rental_date)`?  And if `rental_date` is a date, is `cpd` of the same type?

Comment: helpful, took it out. but now it says "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: Lay your query out in a readable manner, matching parenthesis.  You probably left an extra one in there somewhere.

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to work, can someone help me take the conversion out of the query?

Comment: Is `mre_system_parameters.cpd` a `DATE` field or something else?

Comment: its a number field